# Замена DOM элемента с сохранением его при клике "назад" в браузере

Tags: javascript, jquery, сессия, localstorage

На странице есть кнопка "Добавить к сравнению" и есть код js:

```
jQuery('#compare').delegate('a', 'click', function(){
    ...
});
```

Код работает хорошо, полностью показывать его нет смысла, опишу лишь простую вещь, которую он делает: при клике на элемент идёт `ajax` запрос к скрипту, в котором идёт сохранение (либо удаление) переменной в `суперглобальный массив сессии`, и затем после успешного выполнения `ajax` запроса идёт замена DOM элемента с "Добавить к сравнению" на "Удалить из сравнения" (или наоборот).

Проблем в принципе нет, но если "Добавить к сравнению" (при этом, как мы помним, элемент DOM меняется на "Удалить из сравнения"), затем перейти по любой ссылке, а затем нажать кнопку `НАЗАД` в браузере, то кнопка будет иметь состояние, которое было до выполнения скрипта, то есть "Добавить к сравнению". И только если обновить теперь страницу, то кнопка будет иметь нужное состояние.

Мне показалось, что это некрасиво как минимум, и побегав по сайтам, увидел, что такое же поведение можно встретить много где. Возьмём например онлайн-магазин `OZON`, все его знают. Если зайти на страницу любого товара и добавить его в корзину, то кнопка "В корзину" меняется на "В корзинЕ", затем перейдём в корзину, жмякаем `НАЗАД` в браузере и видим, что товар не в корзине оказывается, но если обновим страницу то всё в порядке.

**Вопрос вот в чём:** будет ли поведение другим, если я вместо сессии использую `LocalStorage`?

Answer (score 1):

По идее при нажатии на кнопку `назад` браузер перезагружает страницу, поэтому скрипты должны загрузиться сразу. Если так, то дело на серверной стороне.

Если же вы каким-то образом работает через `hash` и `history api`, то есть событие `onpopstate` которое срабатывает если мы меняем `hash`, например, при этом страничка по идее не перезагрузится

```
window.onpopstate = function () { 
    console.log("hahs was changed!") 
};
```

А потом смените адрес с `example.com` на `example.com#hash`

Если используете `history api`, то там так же срабатывает событие `onpopstate`, только api немного другое

```
window.onpopstate = function () { 
    console.log("hahs was changed!") 
};
history.pushState({foo: 'bar'}, 'page', '/page/); // меняем адресную строку
```